# USB-connected external graphics card

Tags: linux, driver, gpu, video-card

Is there any way in any Linux-based OS to access the instructions sent to have it transfer the instructions meant for the GPU to an external device connected via USB3.0 (and, obviously get the pixel output back)?
In Windows there is no native support for this kind of thing. Although many external graphics card exist which connect to a PCi slot, I didn't come across any USB ones.
Is there any way to accomplish this with native support of any of the Linux OSes?

EDIT: I was misunderstood, as far as I can see the comments. I want to program an external graphics card, I'm just looking for a way to get the GPU instructions to get to my device and get back the pixel array.

Comment: What external graphics card do you have? Look up *[name of device] linux support* on Google and see if it's supported. Edit: [this thread on the Ubuntu SE](https://askubuntu.com/questions/251500/usb-display-adapter-with-linux-ubuntu-drivers) may be helpful

Comment: Also, asking about device support doesn't really seem like a programming question. Why don't you try [SuperUser](https://superuser.com/)?

Comment: "I didn't come across any USB ones." Then you didn't really look very hard...

Comment: I think you misunderstood me. I want to program a device like so. But how should the driver work?